# calloc returning 2 less characters in char array

Tags: c, gcc

gcc (GCC) 4.4.6

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct B {
    int i;
    char *p;  
} B_t;

B_t b = {
    .i  = 10,
    .p  = NULL
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    struct B *ptr; 

    ptr = &b;

    ptr->p = (char *) calloc(ptr->i, sizeof(char));

    printf("%d,%lu,%lu\n", ptr->i, sizeof(ptr->p), sizeof((ptr->p)[0]));

    return 0;
}

$ make
gcc -g -Wall -o test test.c 
$ ./test
10,8,1
```

Why ?? I am expecting 10,10,1

Answer (score 3):

`p` is a pointer to `char`. The `sizeof()` operator when applied to a pointer will return the number of bytes in a pointer, not the amount of memory allocated for the object pointed to. On your system, the size of a pointer is 8 bytes, so you are seeing 8.

Answer (score 1):

First, `sizeof` works in compile time (with the exception of variable length arrays).

Second, `sizeof(ptr->p)` returns the size of `p` which is a pointer, not what the pointer points. in a 64-bit machine, the size of a pointer is typically `8`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `sizeof(ptr->p)` you're asking about the size of the pointer, not the size of the allocated segment of memory. Since the `sizeof` operator is computed at compile time, you can't use it to know how much memory has been allocated dynamically.

It looks like you have a 64 bit system, so your pointers are 8 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(ptr->p)` returns size of `char *` pointer variable in bytes which is `8 bytes` on 64-bit computers.

`sizeof()` does not return you how much memory you allocated to it using `malloc()`, `calloc()` or other allocation functions.

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** print the size of calloc'ed or malloc'ed memory using sizeof() or by any other simple means, you have to keep track of all dynamically allocated memory by yourself, and you should later free it using `free(ptr_to_allocated_mem)`.

basically, I want to say is what you are trying to print cannot be printed.